# How can I show notification content in my watch app?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, watchkit

I have an AppleWatch app that receives remote notifications. I want the user to be able to open the watch app from a custom notification action and view the item the notification is about. But debugging my Notification scene in my watch app never actually delivers the notification content to my root `WKInterfaceController`, and just keeps spitting out errors like this in the console:

> [default] -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerID:]:2402: ComF: interfaceControllerID for controller:(null) not found (clientIdentifier=(null))
>
> [default] -[SPRemoteInterface _interfaceControllerClientIDForControllerID:]:2414: ComF: clientIdentifier for interfaceControllerID:(null) not found
>
> [default] -[SPRemoteInterface didFinishHandlingActivity:]:2292: ComF:<-Plugin controller ID (null) (object:(null)) has no client identifier

Whether I use a custom notification UI or not (`WKUserNotificationInterfaceTypeCustom` vs `Default`), tapping a button or the notification itself doesn't pass any information through to my root interface controller.

I've implemented [`handleActionWithIdentifier:forNotification:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchkit/wkinterfacecontroller/1648286-handleactionwithidentifier?language=objc) in my root `WKInterfaceController`, but it never gets called. My extension delegate does not implement `handleActionWithIdentifier:forNotification:withResponseInfo:`.

I've tried setting my `WKExtensionDelegate` implementation to the delegate of the `UNUserNotificationCenter` and implementing `userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:`, and that gets called, but I can't seem to get to my root interface controller to have it handle the content. I get the errors above.

Notably, things seem to work once in a while when I make code changes and build and run. But if I rerun the same code it never works - I always get the error messages above.

How is this supposed to work? It must be possible - every messenger app in the world with a watch app does this. But I can't find a tutorial or code example anywhere about how to get notification payload reliably into a `WKInterfaceController` subclass.

**Update:** Interestingly, if I set up my extension delegate as the `UNUserNotificationCenter`'s delegate and handle `userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:`, it works sometimes, but other times I get the error messages listed above, and when I try to get `[WKExtension sharedExtension].rootInterfaceController`, it's `nil`.

Comment: Same problem anyone get any solutions.
(1) How can i get Notification data in InterfaceController.m ? if user click on notification?

(2) How can i get Notification data in InterfaceController.m ? if user do not click on notification.